# How to create import map with jspm2

Tags: javascript, npm, module, node-modules, jspm

I am trying to import javascript packages from npm using JSPM module loader and use offline package loader instead of CDN.
now I want to add an `importmap` script so I can import `react` or another module in  my module like:
 `import React from 'react'`
what can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `importmap` as a standard new way to achieve your goal and import npm module in your js module file without writing a complete path like `node_modules/react@16.x.x/index.js` and just write `import React from 'react'` like previously we used to write in webpack or rollup.
to achieve that after you install jspm and install your needed package with jspm first run the following command:

```
jspm map -o importmap.json --flat-scope
```

it will generate a current importmap for jspm modules and then create a file that contains the importmap data. using --flat-scope is necessary because chrome currently dont support import maps scopes. you must fetch JSON file and inject it into your HTML file. first create a `bootstrap.js` file and paste the following code in it:

```
class bootstrap{
    constructor(){
        this.initMapper().then(()=>{
            this.lunchApp();
        })
    }
     async initMapper() {
        document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('script'), {
            type: 'importmap',
            innerHTML: await (await fetch('/importmap.json')).text()
        }));
    }
    lunchApp(){
        import('/Client/Assets/js/index.js');
    }

}
var app = new bootstrap();
```

then add `bootrstrap.js` into your `index.html` file:

```
<script defer src="/Client/Assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```